# What does "Skip All" do when there is an error copying files?

Tags: files

I am copying files from one hard drive to another hard drive and when I get an error the options listed are "Cancel, Skip All, and Skip". When I select "Skip" the file that caused the error is skipped and copying continues. My quest ion is What happens when "Skip All" is selected?

Comment: Skip All will Skip all future errors (if there will be any) - the future file that may cause an error will not be copied.

Answer (score 0):

Skip all will skip every error it finds in your transfer.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar encounter and when I moved files and clicked skip all upon popup since I wanted to batch rename them later on since originally they were name duplicates but not actual file duplicates BUT after doing the skip all even the folder got deleted, can't find them even with a system backup option. Looks like I managed to delete these forever. SO make sure what you are copying. Dont rush and take it easy.